# running non-static method startActivity(Intent) outside of Mainactivity.class

Tags: java, android, start-activity

I have a Mainactivity class which has a notificationslistener(seperate class), when a notification appears it calls my gethtml class.They both extend activity but the startactivity in my gethtml class doesnt work... (if i copy and test this code in my MainActivity it works fine).. any ideas why?

This is the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.kpbird.nlsexample.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_EXAMPLE");
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NLService.class));
    Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
    startActivity(intent);        

    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

this is the notification listener

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.kpbird.nlsexample.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE_EXAMPLE");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {   
    new Thread(new Runnable() {             
            public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            int cangethtml = 1;
                try{
                    if(cangethtml==1){
                        cangethtml = 0; //only runs once
                        new html();
                    }
                }finally{Looper.loop();}  
            }; 
        }).start();    
    }

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {}
}
```

This is the final class which doesnt open the website through the startactivity.

```
public class html extends Activity{
public html()  {
    Intent i2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            i2.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
            i2.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
            i2.setData(Uri.parse("https://wwww.google.com"));
            System.out.println("hello1");
            startActivity(i2);
            System.out.println("hello2");
}
}
```

Comment: you can use `context` to start activity on non activity class, pass your context to that class and start activity with `context.startActivity();`

Comment: how would I pass context to html.class?

Comment: html class extend activity so it's an activity, what is the problem with `startActivity` on that? add catch and see what happened on that

Comment: But `html` IS an activity; it should be able to use `startActivity`. Try taking out most of it from the try block, OR actually `catch` something.

Comment: Ok, I updated the html.class. It prints hello1 but never gets to hello2.. and I'm guessing never startsactivity(i2)... ;/ and there's no errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to start an activity on the constructor of html, thats your problem.
What you can do is to pass the service context to the html class.

Try this:

```
public html(Context externalContext)  {
        Intent i2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        i2.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
        i2.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        i2.setData(Uri.parse("https://wwww.google.com"));
        i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        System.out.println("hello1");
        externalContext.startActivity(i2); --> START WITH EXTERNAL CONTEXT!!!
        System.out.println("hello2");
```

}

And... injects the notification service context like this:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {   
    new Thread(new Runnable() {             
            public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            int cangethtml = 1;
                try{
                    if(cangethtml==1){
                        cangethtml = 0; //only runs once
                        new html(NLService.this); --> !!!! inject CONTEXT !!!!
                    }
                }finally{Looper.loop();}  
            }; 
        }).start();    
    }
```

Actually... your html doesn't need to extends Activity at all (actually for me html() should be a method of your notification service not a class).

Comment: on the new html(this); it gives the warning :The constructor html(new Runnable(){}) is undefined

Comment: You should put NLService.this sorry.

Comment: Ok, now I get two errors. [2014-03-22 11:00:39 - grabber2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.kpbird.nlsexample/.MainActivity }
[2014-03-22 11:00:39 - grabber2] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: also only gets to hello1

Comment: Errors or warnings? By the way, change from System.out to Log.d.

Comment: You are starting from a service so you should add the next flag: i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.

Comment: that did it!! Carlos, Thank you so much! :P (and everyone else who helped)

Comment: Perfect, please chose like selected answer